# Pulseaudio randomly breaks introducing noise

Tags: pulseaudio

**Setup**

- Arch linux (Antergos)
- XFCE
- Pulseaudio 12.2

**Issue**

Everything works correctly, but sometimes, pulseaudio breaks randomly:

- Delay of 1s in the audio
- Super annoying white noise

This problems are fixed as soon as I restart pulseaudio. Also, I've noticed this problem is triggered 100% of the time when someone is speaking to me trough Discord, but it stops after 5-20 minutes.

Does someone else experience the same situation, or know where should I report this bug? Thank you.

Comment: Yes to the white noise.  I have a "grinding" noise when moving my mouse or moving a window which after a TON of time playing with, came down to audio volumes on the on-board sound card being maxed.  This caused some frequency which is what I was hearing.  Still testing on my end to confirm, but it appears to go away after either turning the volume WAY down, or disabling that card completely (I have an external sound card for my headset, so I don't need on-board sound).